# Verification of Proof that if f(x) is continuous and periodic then it is uniformly continuous on the reals.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Suppose f is defined on all reals.  Then there is a positive p s.t. f(x+p)=f(x) for all x.
This is my proof:

Assume f is continuous on [0,p] then it is uniformly continuous on [-p,p].  Then for x,y in [-p,p] |x-y|<$\delta$ implies |f(x)-f(y)|<$\epsilon$.  Next, if x and y are numbers with |x-y|<$\delta$ then there is an integer j s.t. x+jp and y+jp are both defined in [0,p] and 
$$|x-y|<\delta = |x+jp-y-jp|<\delta ->|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x+jp)-f(y+jp)| < \epsilon $$

I'm not so sure if my period p is positioned correctly in the right intervals.  Can someone please look this over and suggest a correct way of doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Where have you shown that the function is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Um, your domain isn't just going to be $[0,p].$

Answer (score 0):

hint: continuous function and compact subset

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a bit more?